# Parse nested fields in json from REST API into PostgreSQL with psycopg

Tags: python, json, postgresql, python-requests, psycopg2

I'm working on a project in python where I get a json from a REST API using requests and then proceed to load it into a PostgreSQL database. The json the API responds with is strctured like shown below. My main issue is concerning the nested fields, like `location.lat` and the fields nested in the `info` array, like `info[0].value`.

{

> ```
> "items": [
>     {
>         "id": 300436,
>         "item_id_parent": null,
>         "reference": "",
>         "subreference1": "CAMS\/1",
>         "subreference2": "CAMS\/1",
>         "reference_alpha": null,
>         "reference_numeric": null,
>         "oid": "CAMS\/1",
>         "code": null,
>         "code_custom": null,
>         "name": "284",
>         "image": "https:\/\/static.inventsys.com.br\/278\/thumb\/f-3298886-200x200c.jpg",
>         "situations": [],
>         "project_id": 10762,
>         "project": {
>             "id": 10762,
>             "name": "Fauna EGR",
>             "color": null
>         },
>         "category_id": 20685,
>         "category": {
>             "id": 20685,
>             "name": "EGR FAUNA - Armadilhas"
>         },
>         "area_id": null,
>         "area": null,
>         "location": {
>             "lat": -30.136699676514,
>             "lng": -50.910511016846,
>             "address": {
>                 "region": "RS",
>                 "city": "Viamão",
>                 "district": null,
>                 "zipcode": null,
>                 "street": "Rodovia Tapir Rocha",
>                 "street_number": null,
>                 "desc": null,
>                 "full": "Rodovia Tapir Rocha Viamão \/ BR"
>             }
>         },
>         "event_last": null,
>         "description": null,
>         "search_terms": "CAMS\/1 284 Fauna EGR EGR FAUNA - Armadilhas Rodovia Tapir Rocha Viamão \/ BR",
>         "info": [
>             {
>                 "id": 42725,
>                 "name": "Observacoes",
>                 "type": "longtext",
>                 "value": null,
>                 "fvalue": null,
>                 "description": null,
>                 "ikey": null,
>                 "group": "Fauna EGR",
>                 "preload": false,
>                 "filling": false,
>                 "primary": false,
>                 "created": null
>             },
>             {
>                 "id": 44542,
>                 "name": "Data de instalacao",
>                 "type": "date",
>                 "value": null,
>                 "fvalue": null,
>                 "description": null,
>                 "ikey": null,
>                 "group": "Fauna EGR",
>                 "preload": false,
>                 "filling": false,
>                 "primary": false,
>                 "created": null
>             },...
> ```

So far I get that I need to name the fields and establish a placeholder for each variable in my table, and this is what I have thus far:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=guilhermeiablonovski") cur = conn.cursor()

dbarmadilhas = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS egrfauna_armadilhas; CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS egrfauna_armadilhas( id text PRIMARY KEY, name text, image text, category_id integer, category_name text, latitude real, longitude real, imagem_orig text, observacoes text, instalacao DATE, IDcartao text, IDcamera text, IDbueiro text, estrada text, foto_armadilha text, gps_lat real, gps_long real, gps_alt real, gps_acc real);"""

cur.execute(dbarmadilhas) conn.commit()

armadilha_fields = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'image',
    'category_id',
    'category.name',
    'location.lat',
    'location.lng',
    'files[0].url_orig',
    'files[1].url_low',
    'info[0].value',
    'info[1].value',
    'info[2].value',
    'info[3].value',
    'info[4].value',
    'info[5].value',
    'info[6].value',
    'info[7].value',
    'info[8].value',
    'info[9].value',
    'info[10].value',
    'info[11].value' ]

for item in registros:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in armadilha_fields]
    # need a placeholder (%s) for each variable 
    # refer to postgres docs on INSERT statement on how to specify order
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO egrfauna_armadilhas VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", tuple(my_data))

conn.commit()
```

The issue here is that if I run the code with just the first four variables, it works fine, so I guess my syntax is all wrong when it comes to the nested fields I want to parse. How best could I refer to those fields?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference, solved it like so:

```
for item in registros:
    armadilhafields = [
    item['id'],
    item['name'],
    item['image'],
    item['category_id'],
    item['category']['name'],
    item['location']['lat'],
    item['location']['lng'],
    item['files'][0]['url_orig'],
    item['info'][0]['value'],
    item['info'][1]['value'],
    item['info'][2]['value'],
    item['info'][3]['value'],
    item['info'][4]['value'],
    item['info'][5]['value'],
    item['info'][6]['value'],
    item['info'][7]['value'],
    item['info'][8]['value'],
    item['info'][9]['value'],
    item['info'][10]['value'],
    ]
    my_data = [field for field in armadilhafields]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO egrfauna_armadilhas VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", tuple(my_data))



conn.commit()
```